# C# и Sqlite подключение к БД более одного компьютера

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Можно ли подключиться к локальной БД Sqlite по сети? Например если на одном стоит база а с другого компьютера ее подцепить? Реальное такое?

Comment: Это возможно, НО невозможна одновременная работа с базой с разных компьютеров.

Comment: @Bulson вроде в 3 версии была возможность работы в несколько коннектов? Или это только в рамках одного ПК?

Comment: А зачем sqlite? Существует куча других решений. Полноценных и бесплатных в том числе.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite Multiple Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-users)

Теоретически SQLite поддерживает одновременную работу с одной базой данных.

На практике же лучьше всего реализовать подобный сценарий при помощи сервера (предоставляет доступ к данным из SQLite) и клиента.